# Using bash to output several similar lines of text by reading a TSV file and inserting the read values as argument in the text line

Tags: bash, csv, arguments

I am currently trying to use a TSV file to generate lines of code based on a template line given in the function call. Here is an example

TSV file (values.tsv):

```
Title_1 <\t> Body_1 <\t> Footer_1
Title_2 <\t> Body_2 <\t> Footer_2
Title_3 <\t> Body_3 <\t> Footer_3
```

Bash call:

```
cmd values.tsv "\card{$1}{$2}{$3}"
```

Desired Output:

```
\card{Title_1}{Body_1}{Footer_1}
\card{Title_2}{Body_2}{Footer_2}
\card{Title_3}{Body_3}{Footer_3}
```

I currently have a function that executes this example with a hard coded approach but I would like to have a more generic function that can insert the TSV values into a preset line of code based on syntax given above. Here is the hard coded function for reference

```
card_basic()
{
     input=$1 
     while IFS=$'\t' read -r -a cell
     do
          echo -n "\\card{${cell[0]}}{" 
          for x in "${cell[@]:1}"
          do
               echo -n "$x"
          done
          echo "}{}"
     done < "$input"
}
```

Comment: What do $1, $2 and $3 contain?

Comment: They contain nothing. It's just syntax i would like to use. $1 is replaced with cell 1 of whatever row of the tsv we are one $2 is replaced with cell 2 and so on

Comment: does `echo a b c | while read c1 c2 c3 ; do echo $c1 $c2 $c3 ; done` give you any ideas? Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach seems backwards. Try this.

```
awk -F '\t' '{ printf "\\card{%s}{%s}{%s}\n", $1, $2, $3 }' values.tsv
```

I suppose you could pass the format string as a variable if you wanted to, though this really seems like an unnecessary complication, given how little else the Awk script contains.

Comment: Cleaner than this is difficult!